# How to connect the server to Arduino client?

Tags: java, c++, sockets

There is the code of my webclient socket arduino and my java webserver both are running but how to connect them together.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x03};
char server[] = "localhost:8080"; // server name 
WebSocketClient client;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Ethernet.begin(mac);
    client.connect(server); //client connect to the server
    client.setDataArrivedDelegate(dataArrived);
    client.send("Hello World!");
}

void loop() {
    client.monitor();
}
```

*How to connect the server to Arduino client?*

```
void dataArrived(WebSocketClient client, String data) {
    Serial.println("Data Arrived: " + data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class server {
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
server Server = new server();
Server.run();
}
public  void run() throws Exception {
ServerSocket  SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(8080);
Socket sock=SRVSOCK.accept();
InputStreamReader IR= new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
BufferedReader BR= new BufferedReader(IR);
String message = BR.readLine();
System.out.println(message);
if(message!=null){
    PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    ps.println("recieved");
    SRVSOCK.close();
}


} 
this is my server code
```